# Obtener json hacia objeto PHP -> Android studio

Tags: php, android, mysql, json

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]Tengo un php en donde realizo un select a una tabla de regiones, obtengo el nombre y lo retorno a través de PDO como objeto.
Luego en android studio capturo la respuesta, retorna un objeto vacío.

Adjunto imagenes de php y el respectivo código de android
[image: index.php]

[image: Functions.php]

[image: android]

Comment: Hola roberto pasa tus imagenes a texto, como pretenedes que la gente intente resolver tu problema sin poder copiar y pegar. Si te adjuntan la respuesta como imagen por ejemplo tu tampoco podrias copiar y pegar la solucion

Comment: Aparte de lo que dice @LombardaArda, ya que usas retrofit, puedes crearte una clase en Android que sea un reflejo de la respuesta que esperas del servidor, con las mismas propiedades. Luego cambias la declaración del método de retrofit para indicar que la respuesta es un objeto de esa clase y retrofit hará el mapeo de Json dicha clase

Comment: los reswultados que obtengas en PHP haz un echo `json_enconde()` asi cuando leas la paginas solo es obetener el inputStream y pasarlo a JSON nuevamente para que sea tratado de la forma que tnegas planeado un saludo

Comment: Hola roberto, haz visto algo de Volley? yo uso customrequest con Volley para traer la respuesta desde PHP en JSON y luego parseo los resultado con Java y JSONObject.